# Deserializing with SimpleXML

Tags: java, xml, xml-deserialization, simple-framework

**EDIT:** Removed previous edit

I'm trying to deserialize the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ALL>
    <KAMP>
        <ID>1</ID>
        <SQLTID>1376881200</SQLTID>
        <DATO>2013-08-19</DATO>
    </KAMP>
    ...
    <KAMP>
        <ID>2</ID>
        <SQLTID>1376881200</SQLTID>
        <DATO>2013-08-19</DATO>
    </KAMP>
</ALL>
```

Using

```
@Root
public class Matches {

    @ElementList
    private List<Match> list;

    public List getMatches() {
        return list;
    }
}
```

And

```
@Root(name = "KAMP", strict = false)
public class Match{

    @Element(name = "ID", required = false)
    public String Id;

    @Element(name = "SQLTID", required = false)
    public String Sqltid;

    @Element(name = "DATO", required = false)
    public String MatchDate;
}
```

I keep getting

```
Element 'KAMP' does not have a match in class <myClass>
```

I've tried adding `(name = "KAMP")` to `@ElementList` but it didn't help.

Can anyone else help?

Comment: Did you want it to map `Match` to `KAMP` ? You should provide "directions" ;)

Comment: Yes @alfasin. That's what I want. To get a collection/list of Match objects from an XML containing KAMP elements.

Comment: Still nuthin :-( I CAN deserialize a single KAMP element alone in a file but not more than one wrapped in an <ALL> element... must be so close... :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following code works for me, pay special attention to the following two items:

1. empty constructor in ALL.java
2. That the List has annotation of `inline=true`

ALL.java:

```
import org.simpleframework.xml.ElementList;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Root;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Serializer;
import org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * User: alfasin
 * Date: 8/19/13
 */
@Root(name="ALL")
public class ALL {

    @ElementList(entry="KAMP", inline=true)
    private List<KAMP> kamp;

    public ALL(){};

    public List<KAMP>  getMatches() {
        return kamp;
    }

    public static void main(String...args) throws Exception {
        Serializer serializer = new Persister();
        File example = new File("/Users/alfasin/Documents/workspace-sts-3.2.0.RELEASE/SimpleXML/src/kamp.xml");
        ALL all = serializer.read(ALL.class, example);
        for(KAMP tmp : all.getMatches()){
            System.out.println("ID: "+tmp.Id);
            System.out.println("MatchDate: "+tmp.MatchDate);
            System.out.println("Sqltid: "+tmp.Sqltid);
            System.out.println("----------");
        }
    }
}
```

KAMP.java

```
import org.simpleframework.xml.Element;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Root;

/**
 * User: alfasin
 * Date: 8/19/13
 */
@Root(name="KAMP",strict = false)
public class KAMP {

    @Element(name = "ID", required = false)
    public String Id;

    @Element(name = "SQLTID", required = false)
    public String Sqltid;

    @Element(name = "DATO", required = false)
    public String MatchDate;

}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
ID: 1
MatchDate: 2013-08-19
Sqltid: 1376881200
----------
ID: 2
MatchDate: 2013-08-19
Sqltid: 1376881200
----------
```

Comment: "Should define" as in HAVE to? :-) Or can I get around it using attributes?

Comment: @CJe you can change the name of the class if you don't want to use annotations for mapping.

Comment: So I tried renaming my Matches class to ALL and add name = "KAMP" to my Match class - still no good: Unable to satisfy @org.simpleframework.xml.ElementList(data=false, empty=true, entry=KAMP, inline=false, name=, required=true, type=void) on field 'list' private java.util.List

Comment: @CJe it didn't help you since ID, SQLTID and DATO should be "under" KAMP - which means that an object called KAMP should CONTAIN these properties. in your current class they live "as peers" (in parallel)

Comment: Like I suggested on the second part of my answer: 1. change "match" to  "KAMP" and then, 2. create a new class for ALL which will hold a list of KAMP (Match) objects. Make sure your objects have the same structure as your XML

Comment: that I dont understand... ID, SQLTID and DATO *are* under KAMP in my XML. What do you mean by "as peers"? On the same level or...?

Comment: I'll try create classes that match (no pun intended) the XML elements but I really would like for my code to be in English even though the XML elements are named in Danish...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35776/discussion-between-cje-and-alfasin)

Comment: Thanks for the update! Could you elaborate just a bit on especially the empty constructor? Why is that needed? Will give it a go when I get home.

Comment: @CJe I'm not sure why, I can only guess that it has something to do with SimpleXML implementation